# Linear Algebra - Find the two numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of two numbers is $19,712$.

One of the two numbers is divisible by $10$.

If the units digit of the number is erased, the other number is obtained.

What is the product of the two numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can see

$10x+x = 19712.$

$11x = 19712.$
$x = 1792.$

$1792 + 17920 = 19712.$

Ans: $1792 \times 17920 = 32112640.$